# change active menu icon color in DrawerNagivation react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I m creating my first react-native application and i wanted to change css for drawer navigation.i have already tried changes color with activeTintColor but its not working.I just wanted to change the icon color or the menu item which is active.

What i have done is here:

```
    const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  Page1: {
    screen: MainTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home'
    },
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)'
    }
  },
  page2: {
    screen: AboutUs,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'About Us'
    },
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)'
    }
  },
  Page3: {
    screen: LogoutScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Logout'
    },
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)'
    }
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Page1',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the same color for all the menu items when active, This will help you,

```
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  Page1: {
    screen: MainTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home'
    },

  },
  page2: {
    screen: AboutUs,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'About Us'
    },

  },
  Page3: {
    screen: LogoutScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Logout'
    },

  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Page1',
  contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)'
  }
});
```

Comment: I think he asked for the Icon Color along with active text color

Answer (score 0):

According to `react-navigation-drawer version 2.3.3`, I suggest to use `drawerIcon` property in `navigationOptions`

In this example, I used `Ionicons` from `expo/vector-icons` for icons

```
    const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Page1: {
        screen: MainTabNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: 'Home',
          drawerIcon: (tabInfo) => {
               return <Ionicons
                    name='ios-restaurant'
                    size={25}
                    color={tabInfo.tintColor}
                />
          },
        },
        contentOptions: {
          activeTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)'
        }
      },
....
....
....
```